# How to ensure Windows server can share Windows client Clipboard

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, remote-desktop, clipboard

Clients are Windows XP, Servers are 2003 and 2008.

Despite the option to share clipboard always being checked, occasionally the clipboard will not be shared between the two sessions. I can ctrl-c and ctrl-v both  inside the remote session and inside the client, but when I try to copy from the server to the client or vice-versa, it fails.

Is there another setting in addition to the option in Remote Desktop Connection to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this issue now and then and it's drove me crazy. Some times restarting the clipboard service seems to flush it out. I just found this interesting blog which is a good read about why this happens.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2006/11/16/why-does-my-shared-clipboard-not-work-part-1.aspx

Comment: Good read. Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I'll leave this question unanswered as I'm unable to upgrade these corporate machines beyond the XP family.